# Displaying console information in a text area

Tags: java, user-interface

```
 int day = Integer.parseInt(inputDay.getText());
 int month = Integer.parseInt(inputMonth.getText());
 int year = Integer.parseInt(inputYear.getText());

 int dayNow = Integer.parseInt(inputDayNow.getText());
 int monthNow = Integer.parseInt(inputMonthNow.getText());
 int yearNow = Integer.parseInt(inputYearNow.getText());

 //total.setText(day + "/" + day + "=" + day/day);
 System.out.println(((yearNow-year)*365)+((monthNow-month)*30)+(dayNow-day));
```

I am trying to get the *System.out.println* to display on a text area

Comment: what you need is something like `dateNow.setText(((yearNow-year)*365)+((monthNow-month)*30)+(dayNow-day))`

Comment: I have tried putting total.setText(((yearNow-year)*365)+((monthNow-month)*30)+(dayNow-day))

Comment: when I do that I get and error --> method setText in class javax.swing.text.JTextComponent cannot be applied to given types        required: java.lang.string                                            found: int

Comment: try this `total.setText(""+(((yearNow-year)*365)+((monthNow-month)*30)+(dayNow-day)))`

Answer (score 1):

Use a JTextArea and implement the setText() method... try this

```
JTextArea t = new JTextArea();
t.setText(Integer.toString(((yearNow-year)*365)+((monthNow-month)*30)+(dayNow-day)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dateNow.setText(((yearNow-year)*365)+((monthNow-month)*30)+(dayNow-day))
```

Use this to be put by a Logger, using a Rolling File Appender, bring it to the console as well as the file for Log, which can be easily used using IO for future retrieval.